# OSX Mavrick Syslog -> New Log file

Tags: logging, osx-mavericks, syslog

I've got logging enabled on my Mavericks server and everything is being written to system.log.

I've set my MAC syslog server as the remote log server for my network router and this is working fine, but everything is being written to system.log, Ideally I'd like it to go to **/var/log/router.log**

I've created the router.log, and set the ownership and permissions, but how do I send just the router logs to that log file ?

The logs looks similar to this :

```
Mon Apr 28 08:48:10 2014: <12>Apr 28 08:48:00 kernel: DROP IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=203.58.25.11 DST=80.xxx.xx.xx LEN=131 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xA0 TTL=107 ID=96 PROTO=UDP SPT=29604 DPT=50976 LEN=111 

Mon Apr 28 08:48:12 2014: <12>Apr 28 08:48:01 kernel: DROP IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=88.195.144.252 DST=80.xxx.xx.xx LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xA0 TTL=114 ID=17397 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=63285 DPT=50976 SEQ=294340858 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40103030201010402) 

Mon Apr 28 08:48:12 2014: <12>Apr 28 08:48:01 kernel: DROP IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=113.201.73.109 DST=80.xxx.xx.xx LEN=126 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x20 TTL=45 ID=10052 PROTO=UDP SPT=34680 DPT=50976 LEN=106
```

But there are other entries like:

```
Mon Apr 28 09:08:48 2014: <30>Apr 28 09:08:37 dnsmasq-dhcp[228]: DHCPDISCOVER(br0) aa:ad:bb:11:cc:dd 
Mon Apr 28 08:59:15 2014: <30>Apr 28 08:59:05 pptpd[1773]: CTRL: Starting call (launching pppd, opening GRE)
Mon Apr 28 08:59:15 2014: <30>Apr 28 08:59:05 pptp[1774]: Plugin pptp.so loaded.
```

The logs don't show the router name or IP Address, so is the syslog intelligent enough to allow me to log from a specific IP Address or is there some other method. ?

I've read I should use asl.conf, but I'm not sure what to configure to make this work correctly.

Any help or advice would be gratefully received :-)

Thanks

**FOLLOW UP**

I looked at the raw syslog output to find the host and I've added the following to my asl.conf:

```
? [A= Host kernel:] file /var/log/router.log file_max=5M all_max=50M
? [A= Host kernel:] ignore


? [A= Host pptp] file /var/log/router.log file_max=5M all_max=50M
? [A= Host pptp:] ignore


? [A= Host pptpd] file /var/log/router.log file_max=5M all_max=50M
? [A= Host pptpd:] ignore
```

restarted com.apple.syslogd.plist and now the logs are going to router.log.

Couple of questions.
The logs are still going to system.log as well, how do I stop that ? I assumed the ignore would do that..

The log shows as :

```
Apr 29 12:41:12 kernel: Unknown <Warning>: DROP IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=110.200.88.19 DST=80.xxx.xxx.xxx LEN=129 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xA0 TTL=40 ID=5080 PROTO=UDP SPT=20884 DPT=50976 LEN=109
```

Previously there wasn't the  in the log. Anyway to remove that ?

Thanks

Comment: This was useful for me setting up logging on my own Tomato router, so thanks! My logs are ignored from system.log - make sure you put your rules at the *top* of /etc/asl.conf

Answer (score 1):

The second and third ignore rules from your follow-up are not working because you used **prefix match** (`A=`) with wrong prefixes (**pptp:** and **pptpd:**). Removing the colon from the end should fix them.

These are the actual full host names from your example:

```
kernel:
pptp[1774]:
pptpd[1773]:
```

Therefore, you could use **exact match**(`=`) like this:

```
> router.log file_max=5M all_max=50M    
? [= Host kernel:] file router.log
? [= Host pptp\[1774\]:] file router.log
? [= Host pptpd\[1773\]:] file router.log
```

*Notice that you can specify the details about the log file (router.log) only once at the beginning, and you don't need to give the absolute path (/var/log/router.log) as long as you want your file to be in the default place (/var/log/)

Also, because I used host exact match, I had to give the exact names, which in 2 cases contain square brackets (pptp[1774]: and pptp[1774]:) that must be escaped with '\'*

Or, you can use **prefix match**(`A=`) like in your follow-up, to merge the last 2 rules:

```
> router.log file_max=5M all_max=50M    
? [= Host kernel:] file router.log
? [A= Host pptp] file router.log
```

And after, you can add the **ignore rules** which are identical, but have 'ignore' as an action:

```
? [= Host kernel:] ignore
? [A= Host pptp] ignore
```

From the examples you gave it looks like you should take into consideration another host (dnsmasq-dhcp[228]:) that generates logs from your router:

```
? [A= Host dnsmasq-dhcp] file router.log
```

---

You can also apply filters directly on syslog tool for confirmation:

```
syslog -F raw -k Host kernel:        # print raw logs from Host 'kernel:'
syslog -F raw -k Host pptp[1774]:    # print raw logs from Host 'pptp[1774]:'
```

---

One more thing to mention is that some rules can be defined also in `/etc/syslog.conf`, but in OSX you can only filter by 'Facility' and 'Level', lacking the extra options for 'Host' and 'Process' that are present for example in FreeBSD. In this case, `/etc/asl.conf` is indeed the way to go.